# Does Spring framework support clustering and monitoring like Java EE?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

Spring seems to support all the enterprise features that JEE offers, with the exception of clustering, and sophisticated monitoring.

Clustering seems like an important aspect in terms of scalability, and I was wondering if Spring has any support for it, or are there any other way to achieve horizontal scalability in Spring?

Comment: Java EE app servers support things Spring doesn't support itself, like EJB, JMS, etc. In other words, the bits of Java EE that go beyond simple servlets, filters, and JSP. Spring *can* support those things, but requires external support, like an EJB implementation and a messaging service.

Comment: As i know EJB means managed component, so the container offer various services to it like declarative security and stuff. A spring managed bean can also get those services from the spring container. So where lies the difference?

Comment: Please read about ejb, it's too broad for a comment. They're distributed, for one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java EE is a standard with many implementations, Spring is a product. If you use Spring, you don't need a full application server, as the services offered by both are roughly the same. All you need to run a Spring app is a Web container, like Tomcat or Jetty.

Spring is almost always one or more steps ahead in the functionality it offers compared to an application server. However, if standard compliance is a requirement and you don't want to depend on a specific product, you may choose application servers.

Other reason for using an application server together with Spring, are the monitoring and administering facilities provided by the app servers.

Comment: So, basically, monitoring and administering capabilities are the only thing, that an app server does better than tomcat+spring container configuration? Anything else?

Comment: IMHO nothing else. If you need these monitoring and administering capabilities, then app server + Spring would be your best choice. Otherwise Tomcat + Spring.

Comment: what about scalability? i heard something about app server clustering, while tomcat is single server (as i know).

Comment: You can do clustering with Tomcat. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html